# Remove delete button on select2 3.5 tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm referring to [Select2 3.5](http://select2.github.io/select2/).

I want to hide the close/delete button on one of the tags so that it can't be removed.

I can prevent a specific tag from being removed via the `select2-removing` event, and calling `ev.preventDefault()`, however, I also want to visually indicate that it can't be removed.

Is there a way to remove the 'X' beside the tag?

Answer (score 2):

This will get rid of the x button

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: if the select2 is single select option add the below code to get rid of the x button
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{
    display:none;
}

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can hide. The 'X' is placed inside an anchor which has css class "select2-search-choice-close". So you can add css for that

```
.select2-search-choice-close{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to hide it for a *single* tag, not all of them.